# SSIS OlEDB Connection manager Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

When am using sequence container to roll back my transactions in execute sql task i am getting the error
Connection manager  Error: The SSIS Runtime has failed to enlist the OLE DB connection in a distributed transaction with error 0x8004D025 "The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions.".
have set the transaction property to "Required" for Sequence container and inside all dataflow , execute sql tasks.
i am using two sql servers one is source other is target in the network. please help

Answer (score 3):

You can find it by using the command  **dcomcnfg**  on the Run window. Next, Expand all nodes under Component Services, and then you will see Distributed Transaction Cordinator. After that, Right Click to open Properties window, then go to Security tab to enable Inbound/ Outbound messages.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable "Remote/Network Transactions" in the DTS Service located in the sql server server.

Administrative Tools. Component Services

Computers / MyComputer /
Properties / MSDTC /
Security Configuration /
Network DTC Access /
Allow Remote Clients - 
Allow Inbound

Comment: Would you please explain where to find Remote/Network transactions option